# Define new command to strikethrough all text in an \item

Tags: itemize, strikeout

I would like to strikethrough all the text in an \item.
Since \item takes a variable number of arguments, I don't know how to do that.

I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\noitem}{\item\sout}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first
        \noitem second
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

- first
- <s>s</s>econd

What I want is:

- first
- <s>second</s>

Comment: use `\item\sout{second}` anything else is going to be impossibly fragile and bite you later, even if you get it working in simple cases.